# jquery dataTables - class attribute changes with column sort

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have created a table with specific  class attribute where background color of the  depends upon the class attribute. I use static inline css to define the background color.

I construct the table then use dataTables to give me search/sort capabilities. All looks good. Then when I click one of the column sort arrows (native sort feature in dataTables), sort works but all background color disappears.

Is dataTables modifying class attributes as a by-product of sort?

Comment: table is completely reconstructed when sorted. There are cell render methods you can use...what is criteria for setting class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When activating sorting on specific column, dataTables plugin add some classes to `<td>` (.sorting1) and `<tr>` (.sorting_desc/.sorting_asc) elements.

These will be usefull for you:

- [dataTables styling](http://www.datatables.net/styling/custom_classes)
- [sClass attribute](http://www.datatables.net/usage/columns)